# Login com AJAX e PHP com banco de dados(Porque está dando errado?)

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

```js
$(document).on("click","formlogin",function(evt)
{
     $.ajax({
         type:"GET",
         url:"http://localhost:8080/ProjetoXDK/appModelo/www/php/entrar.php",
         data:{
            var cpf =  $('#cpf').val(),
            var senha = $('#senha').val();
            },
         datatype:"json",
         sucess: function(data){
         if ('#cpf' == $cpf || '#senha' == $senha1){
             activate_page("#inicio"); 
             navigator.notification.alert("Bem Vindo");
         }else{
             navigator.notification.alert("CPF ou senha errados");
         }
      }
    });
   });
```

```html
<div class="grid grid-pad urow uib_row_2 row-height-2" data-uib="layout/row" data-ver="0">
                <div id="loginResult" style="display:none;">
                </div>
                <form id="formlogin" name="formlogin" method="GET">
                    <div class="col uib_col_2 col-0" data-uib="layout/col" data-ver="0">
                        <div class="widget-container content-area vertical-col">
                            <div class="table-thing widget uib_w_4 d-margins" data-uib="twitter%20bootstrap/input" data-ver="1">
                                <label class="narrow-control"></label>
                                <input class="wide-control form-control default" onkeypress="this.value = FormataCPF(event)" onpaste="return false;" name="cpf" id="cpf" type="text" placeholder="CPF" maxlength="14">
                            </div>
                            <div class="table-thing widget uib_w_5 d-margins" data-uib="twitter%20bootstrap/input" data-ver="1">
                                <label class="narrow-control"></label>
                                <input class="wide-control form-control default" name="senha" id="senha" type="password" placeholder="Senha">
                            </div>
                            <button class="btn widget uib_w_3 d-margins as btn-default" data-uib="twitter%20bootstrap/button" data-ver="1" id="btnEntrar">Entrar</button><span class="uib_shim"></span>
                            <div id="loginResult" style="display:none;">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><span class="uib_shim"></span>
                </form>
            </div>
```

```css
<?php
session_start();
$uCpf = $_POST['cpf'];
$pSenha = md5($_POST['senha']);
$qry = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE cpf='".$uCpf."' AND senha='".$pSenha."' AND status='active'";
$res = mysql_query($qry);
$num_row = mysql_num_rows($res);
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
if( $num_row == 1 ) {
 echo 'true';
 $_SESSION['uCpf'] = $row['cpf'];
 $_SESSION['pSemha'] = $row['senha'];
 }
else {
 echo 'false';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Deves declarar propriedades do objeto `data` e não declarar variáveis dentro do objeto.

Muda

```
 data:{
     var cpf =  $('#cpf').val(),
     var senha = $('#senha').val();
},
```

para

```
 data:{
    cpf:  $('#cpf').val(),
    senha: $('#senha').val();
},
```

Mais ainda, a linha `if ('#cpf' == $cpf || '#senha' == $senha1){` não faz sentido, ela deve usar a resposta do PHP que neste caso é só `true` ou `false`.